# Why this Git Merge Message? : Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary

Tags: git, vim, github, merge, git-merge

I have 3 Branches: dev, staging, master.

I make a change on dev and commit it.

I change to staging

I merge dev into staging ("git merge dev").

Usually, it would just "copy" my changes over into staging.

But since recently, whenever I type "git merge dev", git opens vim editor and shows me this message:

[image]

to get out of this screen, I type :quit

[image]

it then merges dev into staging, but says it used the "recursive strategy"

[image]

When I check my github history, it now shows both the initial commit and the merge into staging.

Note also the description is the line that was pre-filled in the VIM editor.

[image]

when I merge staging into master, this message does not appear, everything works as usual.

Does somebody know why git does open the VIM editor and makes it so difficult to merge from dev into staging?

Comment: It sounds like there were commits on staging that weren't on dev.

Comment: yes, that's possible